# keep player from sliding on ramp

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

I cant figure out how to make it so the player stays in the same place on an incline while being able to jump instead of sliding down the slope. Also i cant figure out how to make it so the player jumps when i swipe up. What i really am trying to do is keep the player in the center of the slope without sliding down, while being able to jump when i swipe up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `friction` property on the player and/or the slope `SKPhysicsBody` to 1.0. This will increase the friction between the player and the slope so that the player won't slide down.